# {Ctrl} + {Scroll Wheel Up/Down} zooms too fast when viewing .Pdf files in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, pdf, zoom, logitech-mouse

I have the latest Google Chrome (83.0.4103.116), Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (20.009.20067), Windows 10 laptop, Logitech M510 mouse with LogiOptions software (8.20.329).

My issue is that when I open a .pdf file in Google Chrome, and I zoom in/out using ctrl + mouse wheel, the zoom function is extremely fast. For example, at 100% zoom, if I zoom out once (*one scroll wheel tick*), it goes to 40%. From there, if I just zoom in twice, we are already at 256%. What is going on?

This specifically *only* happens when zooming with Ctrl + scroll wheel, *only* for .pdf documents, *only* opened in Google Chrome. Enabling/disabling smooth scrolling, doesn't fix it either.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any other answer than "LogiOptions  is pants" It is on Mac too.

Comment: @Tetsujin damn... I uninstalled logioptions, smooth scrolling obviously disabled, and my problem fixed... I guess I have to look into logitech related solutions then... Thanks for commenting

Comment: Welcome - had you been on Mac I would have had a couple of good suggestions for alternative 'clever mouse drivers' but idk of any equivalent for Windows, sorry. At least you have one of the Logitechs with 'regular' buttons & wheels. The MX2 which I've got has some odd communication with the OS that means you cannot change out the driver/control panel, you're stuck with the Logi :\

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with logitech mouse, in my case it was logitech mx vertical. Except in my case this was issue for both pdf files and google maps, that were scrolling too fast.
I solved the issue by downloading logitech options app and then disabling smooth scrolling.
Hopefully it will help someone else, because when I tried to find solution for that I stumbled on this post.